# what is this "linker error while publishing to Azure? Previous versions of .net worked fine

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-5

Error during publishing the project to Azure, it was publishing just fine prior to net5 upgrade. Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       IL Linker has encountered an unexpected error. Please report the issue at https://github.com/mono/linker/issues
```

But there is really nothing to report. Diagnostic log tells nothing:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
```

All references are for .net 5, except radzen, but it was updated today and per description it should work w/ .net 5

Comment: I'm having the same issue - did you get anywhere?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1255150/vs-2019-v1681-il-linker-stopped-working.html

Comment: No, I did not. like self-hosting framework in publishing setup, "early access to .net5" in azure with no success.

Comment: So I've crated a new project which does publish and copied things over to try and find what's causing the publish to fail. It seems to be my reference to DevExpress.Blazor which I'm using for some form components. Not sure if you're referencing that too? If not I'd remove your nuget packages one by one to determine which is causing the fail.

Comment: @GeorgeHarnwell: 
My status:
I am using Radzen for UI components, so I can't remove it. I updated to the latest Radzen build and removed every reference that is not version 5.0 or higher except Microsoft.apnetcore.proxy which I suspect is the problem. This assembly is of version 0.2 and was last updated 11/2016.  I don't know what it should be replaced with in .net5

Another assembly I am using is csvHelper, but it was updated 11/20/20 by it's author, so don't think it causes the publish issue.

Comment: I am getting the same diagnostic log error when trying to publish a .Net 5 Web API to Azure app service.  Works perfectly local.  I only have 3 packages installed related to Azure services (Blob, Queues) and I can't uninstall them or it won't build.

Comment: @BryanLewis - try doing what I did, create a new Blazor project, and add the nuget packages to the new project one at a time and try to publish. See at which point it fails.